# Format step name in Cucumber nodeJS

Tags: node.js, cucumber

How I can change step name in execution process and apply it for display in report?
On python I did next:

```
def before_step(context, step):
    context.step = step
```

Then I could rename step in execution process. For example if I had `{random}` text in step name I could change it to generated value at apply it for step name

```
@step('some "{value}" to change')
def step_impl(context, value):
    context.step.name = context.step.name.format(random=new_value)
```

And new step name is displayed in report with applied value.

Now I try to do the same trick with `Cucumber` using `nodejs`

```
BeforeStep(async function (step) {
    global.step = step.pickleStep.text
})
```

And then I try to change `random` word in step name to new value

```
global.context.step = global.context.step.replace(/{random}/g, value)
```

But applied value is not applied to report. Something I did wrong.